# What is the difference between "fold back" and "fold up"?

Tags: phrasal-verbs

[image]

I am trying to describe how to form the shape shown in the above picture. The following is my example:

> Fold back/up a strip of paper several times such that the folds are
>   stacked.

According to my dictionaries, what I want to say corresponds to "fold back" or "fold up". Which of the two is better for the shape in the picture?

Comment: Is there a reason you have to pick either? Fold works fine on it's own as I understand it.

Comment: @MattCom  It's perfectly valid to ask the difference between two very similar idioms.

Comment: @Andrew I suppose I was just curious for more context. You're right of course.

Comment: @MattCom  fair 'nuff.  :)

Comment: Fold your paper into rectangles or squares.

Comment: >>Fold your paper into rectangles or squares.  I am afraid that this expression may be interpreted that paper is folded in the same direction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Objectively there is not a lot of difference.  Either way you are *folding* something.

*Subjectively*, though, "fold up" describes the general action, while "fold back" specifically means to fold something to the *opposite* of some direction.  Often this means *back, towards yourself*.

Examples:

> Please **fold up** those boxes so it's easier to throw them away
>
> Lay the paper flat, fold in half to make a crease down the middle, and then **fold back** the leading edge to meet the crease.

If there are multiple folds that go in different directions (as in your example), then it's better to use *fold up* or just *fold*.

Answer (score -1):

"fold up" is the better option.  To fold something "back", describes a specific orientation of what you're folding.  As in, "Facing the box, fold back the top flap to expose the interior of the box."

In this case, you're "folding up the strip of paper as shown".